# How to return 0 when the query return NULL

Tags: php, mysql, php-5.2

My php query look like:

```php
<?php 
$raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT Operator, Data_przegladu, IFNULL(COUNT( Operator ),0) AS operator_count 
                            FROM przeglad 
                            WHERE MONTH(Data_przegladu) = 1 
                              AND Operator = \"Adrian Pikus\" 
                            HAVING (COUNT( Operator ) > 1)") or die(mysql_error());       
$row = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results);
echo $row['operator_count'];
?>
```

The result is NULL but i want the result to be 0. Somebody can help me? I use PHP 5.2 and i can't update it

Comment: *The result is NULL* Do you mean that the query returns empty rowset?

Comment: If the query didn't return any rows, then `operator_count` is an undefined index. If the query ran successfully, you should be hitting the `IFNULL()` function.

Comment: **Warning:** `mysql_*` extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and has been removed as of PHP 7.0.0. Instead, either the [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) extension should be used. See also the [MySQL API Overview](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

Comment: You have already asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64116452/how-to-return-0-when-the-query-return-null) today. Please do not abuse the system to reask the question.

Comment: When would `COUNT( Operator )` be NULL? You can't check for NULL on a function that always returns an integer. What exactly are you asking about?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think the null coalescing operator should do the trick:

**For php 7 and above**

```
echo $row['operator_count'] ?? 0;
```

**Works for all versions**

```
echo $row['operator_count'] ? $row['operator_count'] : 0;
```

Both will print `$row['operator_count']` if it is not null else 0;

Comment: That won't work on PHP 5.2, which is what OP is using.

Comment: I have edited my answer, please have a look.

Comment: echo $row['operator_count'] ? $row['operator_count'] : 0; - it work! Thank you!

Comment: FYI - that would cause *undefined index* notices. Use `isset()`.

Comment: These two are not the same. The second one would cause an error as Qirel pointed out. Besides, the query returns the outcome of `COUNT( Operator )` which should be defined . The SQL needs to be corrected in this case. OP is using the aggregate function in the HAVING clause and this probably produces 0 results for them. IF you wanted to check for that in PHP you would need to use `if($row)` not the ternary

Answer (score -1):

```
$row = is_null($row) ? 0 : $row;
```

You can use [is_null](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php)